# Insert/ Update random date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, random

How would I update a column with a random date in the past 2 weeks using MySQL?

For example (code doesn't actually work):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = sysdate() - rand(1, 14);
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can get a random integer with this expression:

> To obtain a random integer R in the
> range i <= R < j, use the expression
> **`FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j - i))`**. For
> example, to obtain a random integer in
> the range the range 7 <= R < 12, you
> could use the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));
> ```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Use that to generate a random number of days, hours or minutes (depending on the resolution) and add that number to current date.

Full expression would be:

```
-- Date only
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14) DAY;
```

```
-- Date and time
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14 * 24 * 60 *60) SECOND;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63ed026600a8c21159ee7e6d5df57e12)

Comment: This is a really old answer and a really old question, but this solved a problem where I had to introduce over 300 random dates. Thank you!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, This is actually a very indirect way of doing it. Use timestamps http://stackoverflow.com/a/28944156/632951 , it's more straightforward and less prone to errors.

Comment: @Pacerier - Both methods look fine to me (and quite similar). What potential errors do you have in mind?

Comment: @Pacerier Your suggestion is really powerful, but all I wanted was a very basic and quick prototype. The accuracy of the dates wasn't a requirement. I just needed random dates.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, When we need to change "past 2 weeks" to something else like "past 2 months" and etc. My solution is more straightforward and scalable to all use cases because it simply specifies a start_date and an end_date.

Comment: @Pacerier - I honestly can't spot what potential errors can arise by replacing `DAY` with `MONTH`, but having to calculate start and end dates manually is not an enticing argument ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, Calculating the start and end dates are easy: `adddate(now(),interval -2 month)`. And can you spot the error with this? : `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 2) MONTH`

Answer (score 31):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14) DAY
```

This sets `col` to a date between current date - 13 days and current date; both inclusive, total 14 days.

Answer (score 10):

Your main problem is that `RAND()` doesn't allow a range of values like you specify. It will always return a value between 0 and 1.

I can't work out a 1..14 random solution right now, but to get you started, this will pick a random date within the last 10 days:

```
SET col = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ROUND(RAND(1)*10) DAY))
```

Comment: `RAND(seed)`, seed is optional. If seed is specified, it returns a repeatable sequence of random numbers. If no seed is specified, it returns a completely random number. So, your RAND(1) will return always same value (at least for MYSQL)

Answer (score 8):

One simple option is to use this query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = (
    NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14) DAY 
    + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 23) HOUR
    + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 59) MINUTE
    + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 59) SECOND
);
```

Or, more elegant:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = (NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 14 * 24 * 60 * 60) SECOND);
```