# Mysql insert random datetime in a given datetime range

Tags: mysql, sql

With SQL , Can I insert random datetime values in a column giving a range?

For example, given a range of `2010-04-30 14:53:27` to `2012-04-30 14:53:27`

I'm getting confused with the range part. as i will have just done this

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES (RND (DATETIME()))
```

Comment: I want to use it to test my charts

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu, Why would you not want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert/ Update random date in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546111/insert-update-random-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here is an example that should help:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-04-30 14:53:27') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 63072000))
    )
)
```

It uses the date `2010-04-30 14:53:27` as the base, converts that to a Unix timestamp, and adds a random number of seconds from 0 to +2 years to the base date and converts it back to a DATETIME.

It should be pretty close but over longer time periods leap years and other adjustments will throw it off.

Comment: @karto, For handling leap years, see my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28944156/632951

Comment: Love it! Another way, if you want a random date, say, somewhere in the last month:

select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 2592000)))

Comment: Perfect just what I needed :)

Answer (score 31):

This should work nicely:

```
SET @MIN = '2010-04-30 14:53:27';
SET @MAX = '2012-04-30 14:53:27';
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN);
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF` is used to determine the number of seconds in the date range.  Multiply this by a random number between 0-1 results in a random number between 0 and the number of seconds in the range.  Adding this random number of seconds to the lower bound of the range results in a random date between the data range bounds.

Answer (score 10):

This works perfectly **even for leap years**:

```
select from_unixtime(
    unix_timestamp('2000-1-1') + floor(
        rand() * (
            unix_timestamp('2010-12-31') - unix_timestamp('2000-1-1') + 1
        )
    )
)
```

The idea is simple: Just take a random timestamp between the two timestamps, then convert it to a [`datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) using [`from_unixtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). This way you can ensure that each option has equal probability.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way out:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES (SELECT timestamp('2010-04-30 14:53:27') - INTERVAL FLOOR( RAND( ) * 366) DAY);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just try :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2012-04-30 14:53:27')-INTERVAL RAND()*365*2 DAY INTO tbl_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @MIN = '2019-06-29 00:53:27';
SET @MAX = '2019-06-29 13:53:27';

UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN)
WHERE `columnname` = condition
```

Comment: problem was, I have some data for load testing and I want random date in date column in between given range. So every time I use same data & update date column only.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me but my issue was a bit different. I had to assign certain values in a column to a random datetime.

```
    UPDATE Tablename
    SET columnName = addtime(concat_ws(' ','2018-07-25' + interval rand()*2 day 
    ,'00:00:00'),sec_to_time(floor(0 + (rand() * 86401))))
    WHERE columnName = condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but still.. In my case I needed to generate random date in format like this : 2017-01-01.
If anyone will need it I have used @drew010 solution and formatted date with DATE_FORMAT.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 63072000))), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following dynamic query.

```
SET @MIN = NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH;
SET @MAX = now();

select TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN)
```

Thanks to @sapna-bhayal