# mysql random update date column between two date with condition

Tags: mysql

How random update date column between 2014-10-04 - 2014-10-30 only working-days and 08.00 - 20.00 ?

```
2014-10-04 - 2014-10-30 random working-days and random time 8.00-20.00
```

in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @MIN = '2014-10-04 8:00:00';SET @MAX = '2014-10-30 20:00:00';SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN);
```

You can refer [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906572/mysql-insert-random-datetime-in-a-given-datetime-range)