# why isn't this code working? generate date range failed

Tags: mysql, date

I need to generate date between 2015-1-1 and 2015-12-12
my recent code is here

```
set @startdate = '2015-1-10';
set @enddate = '2015-12-12';
select a.Date
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) - (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a where a.Date between @startdate and @enddate
```

from this code i have result truncated date start from 2015-7-29,
but if the code set  date between 2016-01-01 and 2016-12-31 the result is generate full date (perfect)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you do that in SQL? its a query language not a programming one

Comment: Also, please check, if your question has already been asked and answered, before posting a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906572/mysql-insert-random-datetime-in-a-given-datetime-range

Comment: yes i do in sql query

Comment: i can see that, but you shouldn't: come up with a random date in your programming language, query for it in SQL. Doing both in SQL is highly inefficient

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the values are converted to strings for the comparison.

I would just change the formats to be bona fide YYYY-MM-DD:

```
set @startdate = '2015-01-10';
-----------------------^
set @enddate = '2015-12-12';
```

However, the `date` function might also work:

```
where a.Date between date(@startdate) and date(@enddate)
```

EDIT:

I think you have two problems.  First, your arithmetic is off, you are mixing `+` and `-`.  Second, you are doing everything relative to the current date.  You should use the start date.  So:

```
select a.Date
from (select date_add(date(startdate), INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Date
      from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
           ) a
where a.Date between @startdate and @enddate;
```

Comment: the result is still the same