# How to add random interval to timestamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random, timestamp

**We got the following table `mytable`:**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | created    | expired    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 1496476314 | NULL |
|  6 | 1496477511 | NULL |
|  7 | 1496477518 | NULL |
| 12 | 1496477534 | NULL |
| 13 | 1496477536 | NULL |
| 15 | 1496477541 | NULL |
| 21 | 1496477548 | NULL |
| 22 | 1496477550 | NULL |
| 26 | 1496477565 | NULL |
| 28 | 1496477566 | NULL |
| 29 | 1496477583 | NULL |
+----+------------+------------+
```

**We'd like to do the following:**

```
set expired = created + random(15 - 30 minutes) as unix_timestamp where expired is null;
```

I currently have no idea to done it.
If u just can give me some ideas it would save my day.

I tried to convert the `created` timestamp to date_time and add to that date_time the wanted 15 - 30 minutes and finally convert the new_date_time back to unix_timestamp, but there should be an easier way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql insert random datetime in a given datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906572/mysql-insert-random-datetime-in-a-given-datetime-range)

Comment: Thx for the info. I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unix_timestamp` is number of seconds elapsed since 1st January 1970. Now, if you want to add 15 to 30 minutes then the equivalent seconds would be 900 to 1800. Here's what you can do:

```
set expired = created + ROUND((RAND() * (900))+900) where expired is null;
```

This is how it works:

- `RAND()` will generate a random number between 0 and 1
- By using `RAND() * (maximum - minimum)) + minimum` we make sure we generate a number between 900 and 1800.
- `ROUND` then rounds that number to nearest int.

Comment: So the correct way for me is `update mytable set expired = created + ROUND((RAND() * (900))+900) where expired is null;` right?

Comment: Thx for ur help! U saved my day mate :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a random number of minutes between, say, 14 and 33, you can do it like this:

```
SET expired = DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 14 + RAND()*(33-14) MINUTE);
```

If you want to have seconds granularity, you need to add SECOND-typed intervals:

```
SET expired = DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 14*60 + RAND()*(33-14)*60 SECOND);
```

This would saves one datetime conversion if you had a `DATETIME` for the expired column, which makes it slightly easier to expire records (WHERE expired < NOW()). If you have an integer holding a Unix timestamp, then Darshan's answer is **definitely** the way to go, and you'd do well to calculate the Unix timestamp in your app and then plug it in the query:

```
WHERE expired <= 123456789
```

Having an index on that column would make expirations go blazingly fast. I *think* it might be even faster than the datetime method, but it's just a sensation, I haven't actually checked.