# Change a date randomly by +- 5 days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert/ Update random date in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546111/insert-update-random-date-in-mysql)

How to change a date change a date by +- 5 days randomly in mysql?

```
UPDATE student SET date = date*(RAND()*-5,+5)
```

Comment: its in the range of -5 to +5 or its either +5 or -5?

Comment: I am using dreamcoder to edit my table. I have a 1000 rows of data. Each row has a date.I want to randomly change the date by either +5 days or -5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `student` SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL ((1 - ROUND((RAND()))*2)*5) DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT 5 + ROUND(RAND()) * -10` will give either **5** or **-5** which you can combine with the [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

Answer (score 0):

Following query outputs random date +-5 days from now (CURDATE())

```
select ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ROUND(RAND()*10)-5 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
select case when (RAND()*10) >= 5 then date_add(<date_col>, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
            else date_add(<date_col>, INTERVAL -5 DAY)
            end
from <your_table>
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4312)

you Could Update your table like this:

```
UPDATE student SET `date`=
 case when (RAND()*10) >= 5 then date_add(`date`, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
            else date_add(`date`, INTERVAL -5 DAY)
            end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE student SET date = ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL ROUND((rand() * 9) - 4) DAY);
```