# How to generate random date in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
       This is my table
       +----+---------------+
       | id | payperiod     |
       +----+---------------+
       |  1 | Weekly        |
       +----+---------------+
       |  2 | Monthly       |
       +----+---------------+
```

I need to use query to show two date NextPaydate and SecondNextPaydate in future with payperiod 
if payperiod is Weekly then nextpaydate would be  07/01/2013 and secondnextpaydate would be 07/07/2013

I did solution with php code as below

```
$payperid = 'Weekly'; // value can be changed
if ($payperid == "Weekly") {
    $rand = rand(2,6);
    $diff = 7;
}
else if ($payperid=="Monthly") {
    $rand = rand(2,28);
    $diff = rand(30,31);    
}
$opt_in = date('Y-m-d');
$ed = strtotime($opt_in);

$paydate1_day   = date("d",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+$rand,date('Y',$ed)));
$paydate1_month = date("m",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+$rand,date('Y',$ed)));
$paydate1_year  = date("Y",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+$rand,date('Y',$ed))); 
$paydate2_day   = date("d",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+($diff),date('Y',$ed)));
$paydate2_month = date("d",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+($diff),date('Y',$ed)));
$paydate2_year  = date("d",mktime(date("H",$ed),date("i",$ed),date("s",$ed),date('m',$ed),date('d',$ed)+($diff),date('Y',$ed)));

$nextpaydate = $paydate1_month / $paydate1_day / $paydate1_year 

$secondnextpaydate = $paydate2_month / $paydate2_day / $paydate2_year
```

please help how to do with mysql query (if condtion and rand function)

Comment: Why do you want random paydates? What exactly do you want them to be? Can you try to describe what you want in text rather than PHP code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546111/insert-update-random-date-in-mysql

Comment: I think that you want to know which day the next payday is. If yes, you have to store the last payday and than add the period to it: $date1 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($lastpaydayWeek) + 1 weeks); $date2 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($lastpaydaymonth) + 1 months);

Comment: As my requirement we do not collect paydates from user , we just collect payperid('weekly','Biweekly','montly') based on I need to generate paydates , first I collect data from user and inserts into table then  listing on page with paydates based on user input payperid

Comment: I'm not going to read through the entire code, trying to deduce what it is you're actually after, but perhaps this helps: `DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL ROUND(10*RAND()) DAY), '%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 3):

I am answering the question in your title, since I am unsure after looking at your description.

> How to generate random date in Mysql

```
UPDATE tablename SET datefield= ’1980-01-01′ + interval rand()*80000 day
```

[Taken](http://acsummer.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/quick-answer-add-random-dates-to-mysql-database/) from a Google search: [`random date mysql`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=random%20date%20mysql&oq=random%20date%20mysql&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62j60j62.1970j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

---

### Possible solution

From what I understand of your description:

How to get next week:

```
UPDATE tablename SET datefield = datefield + interval 1 weeks
```

How to get next month:

```
UPDATE tablename SET datefield = datefield + interval 1 months
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate content on-site, instead leave a comment and/or close-vote the question.

Comment: I have update my question according to the description of the OP. Thank your for teaching me this though, I might do the proper action next time.

Comment: Question by the OP still is not a good programming question because OP misses to outline where specifically the problem is programmatically resulted in. It's not a biggie to not know something, however, the question itself must be greatly improved to match the quality requirements of this website to be honest.