# How to randomly generate date between specific date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried this :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 2017-01-01', '2017-02-01 ';)), 2017-01-01 );
```

I want to generate randomly date from 1 of month to 30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert/ Update random date in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546111/insert-update-random-date-in-mysql)

Comment: There are so many things wrong in this snippet, from unmatching single quotes (`'`)  to the absence of a `FROM` clause, etc.

Comment: @Muhammad May be you have to write like this.

`SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2013-01-07', '2013-12-24 ')), '2013-01-07')`

Comment: @roberto06 I am new to stack overflow  can you just explain that we have to generate random date from 2017-1-1  to 2017-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2013-01-07', '2013-12-24 ')), '2013-01-07')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(
 ROUND((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-24')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-07')))+UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-07'))
),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

For first `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, use higher date, for second and third `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, use lower date.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL:

DECLARE @StartDT DATE = '2017-01-01'
  , @EndDT DATE = '2017-01-31'

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDT)
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
          FROM      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDT, @EndDT)

Comment: Please try something like this in MySql

Answer (score 0):

well I think this is **solution**

```
 SELECT '2017-01-01' +  INTERVAL ROUND(RAND() * (30-1) + 1) DAY
```