# Update values with random date

Tags: mysql, database, random

Probably this question is asked a million times, but here it is again. I need to update a table with random date values. The table name is review and it has the following columns: review_id, created_at, entity_id, entity_pk_value, status_id, group_code. I need to update created_at for all the rows and the other values need to remain the same.

The random query that i found is this

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-14 14:53:27') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 63072000))
    )
```

What i have so far

```
UPDATE 'mage_review' 
   SET review_id = ""
     , created_at = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-14 14:53:27') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 63072000)))
     , entity_id = ""
     , entity_pk_value = ""
     , status_id = ""
     , group_code = ""
```

Comment: Well, I guess the first thing to say is that 'mage_review' is a string. Might be an idea to sit down with the manual.

Comment: why you set other columns to empty string? You said "other values need to remain same".

Comment: You are right: this has already been asked: [Insert/ Update random date in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546111/insert-update-random-date-in-mysql)